# Laravel model containing multiple classes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel, coming from Codeigntier. I am trying to get to grips with the model/classes/eloquent convention that Laravel uses. I know that I can make a table in my database called, say, "categories". Then I can make a file in my models folder called category.php containing just the following code:

```
Class Category extends Eloquent { }
```

which automatically connects with the table name with the plural version of the name ("categories") and gives me access to all the Eloquent commands in my controller like `Category::All();`

Here's what I don't get: Do I need to make a new model for every table in my database? In that case I will end up with a bunch of files in my models folder with names like resource1.php, resource2.php, etc, each just containing the same code as above (replacing the name of the class).

Can't I just make one model called, say, "database_handler.php" and then just put all these classes into it in the same place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `database_handler.php` file and do:

```
<?php

    Class Category extends Eloquent { }
    Class Post extends Eloquent { }
    Class Client extends Eloquent { }
```

You can do whatever PHP let's you do, and add many classes to a single `.php` file is something you can do. But this is not a good practice and Laravel is all about developing application using the best ones.

To load this file automatically, you can do one of many things:

1) Add this file to your app/models folder.

2) Add an entry for it on your composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/database_handler.php"
    ]
},
```

And then you'll have to

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

3) Create a different folder for it and also add it to composer json autoload section.

You choose, Laravel will let you free to do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, Antonio. But how do I then call these classes. I tried this and it gives me an "unable to load class" error. So it seems I need to manually load the database_handler.php file?

Comment: You need to run composer dump-autoload to rescan your models directory for multiple classes within the files.